# Why can't I connect to Hive metastore?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

So, I'm using `gcloud dataproc`, `Hive` and `Spark` on my project but I can't connect to `Hive metastore` apparently.

I have the tables populated correctly and all the data is there, for example the table that I'm trying to access now is the next on the image and as you can see the parquet file is there (stores as parquet). `Sparktp2-m` is the master of the `dataproc cluster`.

[image]

Next, I have a project on IntelliJ that will have some queries on it but first I need to access this **hive data** and it's not going well. I'm trying to access it like this:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Check")
            .config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://hive-metastore:9083")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();

    JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<Object, String>, Integer> mr = spark.table("title_basics_parquet").toJavaRDD()...
```

And next, I build the **jar** and send it as a job like this:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --jars target/GGCD_Spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --class parte1.Queries --cluster sparktp2 --region europe-west1
```

And the error is:

[image]

Am I missing something, or is it the wrong **URI**?

Comment: The URI doesn't look correct, if you are using the default hive metastore, try `thrift://<master-node-hostname>:9083`.

Comment: Also, Spark on Dataproc is configured with the correct Hive metastore address, you don't need  to add `.config("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://hive-metastore:9083")` in your code.

Comment: @Dagang I tried `thrift://<master-node-hostname>:9083` inside of the .config and it worked fine, thank you!!

Comment: Did you try removing `.config`? Also I added an answer, could you accept it?

Comment: @Dagang I didn't try removing config, I just changed the `URI` in there. Also accepted and thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Hive Metastore `thrift://<master-node-hostname>:9083`.